# Is this Ghost in the Shell Volume complete?

Tags: merchandise, ghost-in-the-shell

I'm looking to buy the Ghost in the Shell Manga on ebay, and I'm confused.

On one hand, I see an offer for about 5€ for the book with the 
**EAN: 9783897485037**. No page count or further info is given.

On the other hand, I see an offer for about 23€ for the book with **EAN 9781935429012** and **ISBN 1935429019**, the last one also mentiones a page count of 368 pages.

Now, GitS was apparantly first published in a serialized form, and the first bunch of the series was then published as one book. This is what I want to buy. I'm worried that the first, cheaper book might only contain part of the series. I know that there's GitS 1.5 and GitS2:MMI, I'm asking about the first Volume. I lack the knowledge of the vast Manga-databases* where I can simply look up with my EAN/ISBN number what I'm looking at, can someone help?

Edit: I'm looking for German or English versions.

*They must exist, right?

Comment: You don't mention the language you are looking for.  The cheap one is a German translation if that matters.

Comment: Oh yeah, the cheap one was an anime comic, not the original manga. Not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to the manga by Masamune Shirow, there are [3 volumes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell_%28manga%29#Publication_history) the first volume was initially published by Dark Horse in the US. Currently all 2 volumes of the main series and the 1 volume "interquel (Vol. 1.5)" have been republished by Kodansha Comics USA

[Volume 1](http://www.randomhouse.com/book/166169/the-ghost-in-the-shell-volume-1-by-shirow-masamune/9781935429012/) has:

> Pages: 368 | ISBN: 978-1-935429-01-2

[Volume 2](http://www.randomhouse.com/book/200115/the-ghost-in-the-shell-volume-2-by-shirow-masamune/9781935429036/) has:

> Pages: 312 | ISBN: 978-1-935429-03-6

[Volume 1.5](http://www.randomhouse.com/book/213293/the-ghost-in-the-shell-15-by-shirow-masamune) has:

> Pages: 176 | ISBN: 978-1-935429-96-8

Most of these volumes are also available on Amazon.de (if not you can get them on Amazon .com), if that's more convenient for you.

[Vol. 1](http://www.amazon.de/The-Ghost-Shell-Volume-SAC/dp/1935429019), [Vol. 2](http://www.amazon.de/The-Ghost-Shell-Volume-Man-Machine/dp/1935429035/), [Vol. 1.5](http://www.amazon.de/The-Ghost-Shell-1-5-SAC/dp/1935429965/)

Comment: Are all the editions you mentioned complete (apparantly kodansha censored a recent edition)? Also, this is exactly the answer I was hoping for!

Comment: As far as those from this author, yes.